# Question about the centralizer and conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $H$ a non trivial normal subgroup of $G$. I want to prove that $H\cap Z(G)\neq 1$.

I define a relation in $H$ by $x\sim y$ if and only if there exists $g\in G$ such that $x=g^{-1}yg$. This is well defined because $H$ is normal. Thus, the equivalence classes satisfy that $|[ x]|=1$ if and only if $x\in H\cap Z(G)$.

Therefore, if $H=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n[ x_i]$, then $$|H|=|H\cap Z(G)|+\displaystyle\sum_{i}|[x_i]|.$$

I'd like to know that $p$ divides $\displaystyle\sum_{i}|[x_i]|$.

Maybe it is $|[x_i]|=[G:C_H(x_i)]$, or rather $|[x_i]|=[H:C_G(x_i)]$? Which one is it? And how can I prove it? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that in your Class Equation-like formula for $\;|H|\;$ and in what follows you are thinking of something like a group action...yet you did not define one (or did you?), you only define an equivalence relation on $\;H\;$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty close to what you did: define an action of $\;G\;$ on $\;H\;$ by

$$g\cdot h:=h^g:=g^{-1}hg\;,\;\;g\in G\;,\;\;h\in H$$

As with what you did (exactly the same but with other view), this is clearly an action, and for $\;x\in H\;$ we have that $\;|\mathcal Orb(x)|=1\iff x\in H\cap Z(G)\;$ , so we can put

$$|H|=|H\cap Z(G)|+\sum^._{x\in H\setminus Z(GP)}|\mathcal Orb(x)|$$

with $\;\sum^._{}\;$ denoting sum over different, and thus disjoint, orbits

But for each $\;x\in H\;,\;\;|\mathcal Orb(x)|=[G:G_x]\;,\;\;G_x:=$ the isotropy group (=stabilizer) of $\;x\;$ , and this is a power of $\;p\;$ . Since $\;|H\cap Z(G)|\ge 1\;$ , this **must also** be a power of $\;p\;$ and we're done

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How do you know that $Z(G)$ is non-trivial to begin with?